# geth 1.5 - static-nodes.json location for a private network ? File ignored?

Tags: go-ethereum

Since upgrading to 1.5 the file `static-nodes.json` seems to be ignored, same deal with `trusted-nodes.json`

I am confused on what the location should now be.

The [documentation](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/network/connecting-to-the-network.html#static-nodes-trusted-nodes-and-boot-nodes) states that

> You can configure permanent static nodes by putting something like the following into /static-nodes.json (this should be the same folder that your chaindata and keystore folders are in)

However `keystore` and `chaindata` are now in different directories for private a network in 1.5.

The peers run with the `--nodiscover` flag

Has anyone managed to get it working on 1.5 for a private net and how ?

Note: `admin.addPeer` still works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is know issue with early releases of geth 1.5, see  https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3329